# How to differentiate between real users and bots / apps on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

On Google Analytics (GA), I see many visits from various countries some of which I doubt actual users or not. As a beginner, my basic doubt is does GA differentiates the real user at all? Or the Javascript just considers the server requests?

Is there any way for webmasters to know the real users? What is the industrial practice used in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no WebBot traffic should be showing in your GA data.  Certainly the javascript DOES NOT consider server requests;  javascript is purely client side and does not translate into what actually hits your server.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics collects data using javascript, which is typically not used by bots. In my experience, the visits from "unlikely" countries often come from Google Image Search and suchlike.